# In concrete5 how do you create a stand alone script that uses concrete5 built in models

Tags: php, concrete5

I need to create a script that reads data on a concrete5 site. I do not want to create a new db connection or create a database connection outside of the concrete5 api environment. Is it possible to include some scripts from the concrete5 cms and somehow have access to the models so that I can access the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways.

The simplest is via the web server (including a CURL request from the command line) to access a `tools` file. Check out the `[root]/concrete/tools` directory for examples. You'd put it in `[root]/tools`. Tools are much simpler than a single page, but get all the models loaded, etc.

Otherwise, you can run from the command line. See http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/documentation_efforts/how-to-running-concrete5-from-php-command-line/ . Same deal applies -- you'll get the basic models automatically, and you can use Loader::whatever() like normal.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from concrete5 version 8, you can execute PHP scripts in a terminal (bash, Windows command line, ...) using the `c5:exec` CLI command.

For instance, if your script is named `exec-me.php`, you can execute it with the following command:

```
concrete/bin/concrete5 c5:exec exec-me.php
```

(Under Windows, simply replace the `/` with `\`)